# Flutter how to move an item to the bottom

Tags: flutter

I have this two items that once needs to appear in the middle but the other other needs to move to the bottom.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   color: Colors.blue,
   child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text(
        'K',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 200,
          color: Colors.white,
          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [Text('hello')],
      )
    ],
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

This is how it looks.

[image]

I want to move the Hello Text to the bottom. How can I do that?

Comment: non of solution work. The alignment does not move the text to the bottom my guess it's the space is not available. The Spacer move the K to the top and the text to the bottom.

Comment: The Expanded Widget move my K to the Top and the Hello to the bottom.

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot you still have a Text K.

Comment: Hey @user3862830 I have given another answer. Please check that out :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use two things for that, to make it work more efficiently. These are:

- [Expanded Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) -> This will provide space, that is, takes up the remaining space
- [Align class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) -> This will help you to align the item

**Please note**: `Align()`, itself, cannot aligns, the item, unless space is given. If you just use the `Align()`, you will not see any change, because `Text('Hello')` looks for space, but no space is there.

**Code**:

```
      Container(
       width: double.infinity,  // <-- Takes up total width of the device
       height: double.infinity, // <-- Takes up the total height of the device
       color: Colors.blue,
       child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2, // <-- Flex takes care of the remaining space ratio
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'K',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 200,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                ),
              )
            )
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text('Hello', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0))
          )
        ]
      )
     )
```

**Result**:

[image: Resultant Screenshot]

Comment: This is a good answer but what if his hello text has a bigger FontSize? It's going to push the K up. K is not going to be centered anymore.

Comment: That's true, for that you can use [Flutter Stack class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) @Uni. If you want that answer, let me know :)

Comment: you can keep it. Its also a good one since this text is small. It would be good to let the OP know the limitation of this.

Comment: I asked it for you, if in case, you are still figuring how to achieve what you want. I can add the answer to it, and then you can mark this answer, so that people would know about different approaches. @Uni

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your K text to move on top, you would have to use Stack. This way, your widget inside can position themselves anywhere they want.

```
Stack(
alignment:Alignment.center,
children:[
Text("K"),
Align(
alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
child:Text("hello"),
),
]
),
```

Take a look at the stack widget here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8

Comment: Yeah I Just started coming from a react background. Can I also place buttons at the bottom with the Alignment widget?

Comment: Yes. Align lets you align the widgets anywhere you want as long as the widget has the space around it to move around. Spacer, on the other hand, takes the maximum space possible, making the Text below it go to the most bottom part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Spacer(),
      Text(
        'K',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 200,
          color: Colors.white,
          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [Text('hello')],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

how about this way? add two Spacer

Comment: spacer doesn't accurately center the k text though